# If $F(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)$ then show $\sum_{n = 1}^{N} F(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} f(k)[\frac{N}{k}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

This is a question from Elementary Number Theory by Burton

> If $F(n) = \sum_{d|n} f(d)$ then show $$\sum_{n = 1}^{N} F(n) = \sum_{k = 1}^{N} f(k)\left[\frac{N}{k}\right]$$
>   where $[.]$ is the greatest integer function.

At first, it is clear that for number $1 \le k \le N$, it divides exactly $[N/k]$ integers from $1$ to $N$. So this equality seems correct as $f(k)$ will appear $[N/k]$ times following definition of $F$.

But how to write it in form of a proper proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you explained it was very clear. Now, if you want to be very formal you may write as follows:

$$\sum_{n\leq N}F(n)=\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{d|n}f(d)=\sum_{n\leq N}\sum_{d\leq N}f(d)\delta(d|n)$$
We can interchange the sums (Fubini) to get
$$=\sum_{d\leq N}\sum_{n\leq N}f(d)\delta(d|n)=\sum_{d\leq N}f(d)\sum_{n\leq N}\delta(d|n)=\sum_{d\leq N}f(d)[N/d]$$

Comment: Why $\sum_{n\leq N}\delta (d|n)=[N/d]$ ?

Comment: $\delta(d|n)$ contributes when $n$ is a multiple of $d$. We have $[N/d]$ multiples of $d$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{n=1}^N F(n)=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{d\mid n}f(d)=\sum_{d=1}^n f(d)\sum_{kd\leq N}1=\sum_{d=1}^Nf(d)\sum_{k\leq \left\lfloor \frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor} 1=\sum_{d=1}^Nf(d)\left\lfloor\frac{N}{d}\right\rfloor $$